# Insert each row of data to database

Tags: php, mysql

How to save the inserted data from user in every row into database?
[This form is blank and user will insert the following data like Name, Mark, and Gred for every row depends on the no of student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aKff.jpg)

[this is example inserted data by user and when user click submit button, all the data in every row will save into database. So How do i do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnhL6.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

//First we need to make a connection with the database
$host='localhost'; // Host Name.
$db_user= 'root'; //User Name
$db_password= '';
$db= 'student'; // Database Name.
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO student_info (No, Name, Mark, Gred) VALUES ";
for ($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['No']); $i++) {
    $query .= " ({$_POST['No'][$i]}, '{$_POST['Name'][$i]}', '{$_POST['Mark'][$i]}', '{$_POST['Gred'][$i]}'),";
}

mysql_close($conn);
 
?>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="800" border="2" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>NO</td>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>MARKS</td>
      <td>GRED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><label for="Name"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Name[]" id="Name" /></td>
      <td><label for="Mark"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Mark[]" id="Mark" /></td>
      <td><label for="Gred"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Gred[]" id="Gred" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><label for="Name"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Name[]" id="Name" /></td>
      <td><label for="Mark"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Mark[]" id="Mark" /></td>
      <td><label for="Gred"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Gred[]" id="Gred" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <center><input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton" value="Submit" /></center>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your code currently do? Are you getting any errors? Can you post your current code? If this is just a question of how to add data to a database this is too broad and there are many tutorials on that.

Comment: didn't you already ask this http://stackoverflow.com/q/33773984/

Comment: @chris85 doubting we'll get any definite answers.

Comment: Don't do `count($_POST['No']` in a `for`, just use a `foreach`. Check if the form has been submitted first. Don't just send user input into your SQL statement. This opens you to SQL injection.

Comment: @chris85 foreach? pls give example

Comment: There are examples on the manual entry, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have connected to the database using MySQLi or PDO and are on a local server.

To do that you would need to use the mySQL "INSERT" Statement;

```
    INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

If this is what you need please research - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Good Luck

Comment: `mark,937.w23583y5` that will fail (strings) and isn't proper syntax. I think you're in for a long haul on this one.

Comment: Yup im aware that in particular will fail but the questioner would need to research a bit more so a better answer can be given. Please research The right way in doing the Insert IF that is the solution you're looking for.

Comment: so why give invalid syntax? You're just passing along bad coding habits. Not to mention for future visitors to the question/answer who'll think that's valid. You're sending the wrong message.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i copied that from w3schools. the syntax provided not to be copied but as a reference. I guess it was an error on my part

Comment: That link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp shows explicit syntax in the code example `VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway')` quotes around strings.

Comment: Fair enough, Hope this helps him out, Thanks

Comment: You really should adjust your answer, should my comments suddenly disappear, rendering your answer invalid without my comments. Stack wants their site to be an informative one and with truthness, not likeness.